# "manufacturing time" vs. "manufacture time"

Tags: meaning

Why is the term "manufacturing time" used instead of "manufacture time"?

Just like one would say "production time" and not "producing time".

Comment: Because there's no word "manufaction"?  That is, apparently for "producing time" we prefer an -ion form to the -ing form, but if we tried to use that rule to replace "manufacturing", we'd wind up with an impossible word.

Comment: The Merriam-Webster provides the following examples of MANUFACTURE which show that the word is used like the -ion form:
"materials used in the manufacture of cars"
"We're developing new methods of paper manufacture."

Comment: How can MW be right, if it says that?  If "manufacture" were used like an -ion form, it would be obligatorily substituted for the -ing form in "manufacturing time".  But as you point out, it's not.

Comment: Like most "why" questions about language, the whole of the answer is "because that's how it is" Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps the later might be confused with "time of manufacture"?

Comment: The example given in M-W demonstrates the sense of _process_, not of _materials_. So it is not an apt example for that definition. Yes, sometimes dictionaries (especially online versions) make such errors.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch: quite right. But for OP's benefit, let me explain that "time of manufacture" can mean _when it was made_, not necessarily _how long it takes/took to make it_.

Comment: @Greg Lee: You're right, but you are supplying a circular argument—or, at best, one that disputes a dictionary's definition.  I choose rather to take issue with their example; see my other comment.

Comment: Please edit your post, include the definition and examples you found online which will explain "why" you are asking. Otherwise this question is doomed to be closed because it is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Because Manufacture is Verb, Production is not.
Manufacturing is Noun and so is Production.

Hence, '*Production* Time' and '*Manufacturing* Time' (*Noun Forms*)

Comment: Yes. And it's impossible to manufacture time. We only get 24 hours in a day, no matter what we do!

Comment: How can manufacture be a verb when you can say "the manufacture"?